# jsonPayload logging.googleapis.com/trace_sampled not mapping to traceSampled

Tags: google-cloud-stackdriver

I have a custom logging where I am using structured logging with JSON and I could map the trace and spanId fields but trying to do the same with traceSampled didn't work. The field appears as "logging.googleapis.com/trace_sampled" in the jsonPayload object. I did this as per 
https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent/configuration#special-fields

How do I get traceSampled working with structured logging?

Comment: Is there a reason you need to use traceSampled? Can you simply omit that field and use the trace and spanId fields to create the association?

Comment: My custom logging currently uses Operation and emits separate entries at the start and end. In the trace viewer, they show up as two separate events even though they have the same span id that is unique. So I thought setting this might help with visualizing them as a single span as opposed to two separate events. The real goal is to emit separate log entries at the start and end and get them recognized as a span.

Comment: To my knowledge, that's not what these fields are intended for.  They are intended to allow you to associate traces with log entries as per this guide: https://cloud.google.com/solutions/troubleshooting-app-latency-with-cloud-spanner-and-opencensus#correlating_traces_with_logs . They do not allow you to have Trace convert log entries into traces.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using Stackdriver Trace? It seems like it would get the info you're looking for. https://cloud.google.com/trace/

Comment: That might be the last resort but I am looking for a solution with just logging.